# Match string in columns of two data frames and create a new column

Tags: r

I am trying to match the `State` column of `df2` with the `State` column of `df1`:

- the number of rows in both dataframes is unequal.
- the `State` column of `df2` contains multiple values separated by commas.
- when one of the values from `df2` matches with values in `df1`, I want the matching value in a new column `Verified_State`.
  *Note: This is dummy data. There are least chances of more than one match in a single row.*

Input is as follows:

```
df1
  CustomerId State
           1 Alabama
           2 Maryland
           3 Ohio
           4   Texas
           5   California
           6   Alabama

df2
  CustomerId   State
           2 Alabama,North Caroline, Virginia
           4 Alabama, West Virginia
           6    Ohio, Kentucky`
```

Desired output:

```
df3
  CustomerId   State                            Verified_State
           2 Alabama,North Caroline, Virginia     Alabama
           4 Alabama, West Virginia               Alabama
           6    Ohio, Kentucky                    Ohio
```

Comment: What happens if more than state in the CSV list matches the verified list?  Also, storing unnormalized CSV data in your data frame like this is generally bad practice.

Comment: Agreed. This is a dummy data. But unfortunately I got the data in this format. However, matching line by line will least likely have more than one match.

Comment: Then please tidy up your question.

Comment: Just did. Thanks Sir.

Comment: `df2$State` is a column of comma-separated string. But it would be better it it was a vector, then you could directly just do `match(df1$State, df2$State)` or `df1$State %in% df2$State`. This also avoids partial matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` possibility. We use `separate_rows` to separate comma-separated values into different rows and then find out which `State` are present in `df1` for each `CustomerId` and then select only the first match.

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(df2, Verified_State = 
df2 %>%
   separate_rows(State) %>%
   group_by(CustomerId) %>%
   summarise(Verified_State = df1$State[which.max(df1$State %in% State)]) %>%
   pull(Verified_State))


#  CustomerId                          State Verified_State
#1          2 Alabama,NorthCaroline,Virginia        Alabama
#2          4           Alabama,WestVirginia        Alabama
#3          6                  Ohio,Kentucky           Ohio
```

The above would work if there is at least one match in every row. If there could be a case where there is no match at all we can check that case with an `if` condition

```
bind_cols(df2, Verified_State = 
df2 %>%
   separate_rows(State) %>%
   group_by(CustomerId) %>%
   summarise(Verified_State = if(any(df1$State %in% State)) 
   df1$State[which.max(df1$State %in% State)] else NA) %>%
   pull(Verified_State))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. There are chances of no match.

Comment: @Ehsan so the second version should work for your case.

Comment: it gives error as "Error in cbind_all(x) : Argument 2 must be length 1, not 16866". Since the columns are of unequal length in both dataframes. I need to match only df2. Can you suggest something plz?

Comment: Even if columns are of unequal length this should still work. I am not able to reproduce the issue with the current example. Can you edit and provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using `grep`. Below is an example in base R:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(State = c("Alabama", "Maryland"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df2 <- data.frame(State = c("Alabama,North Caroline, Virginia",
+                             "Ohio, Kentucky"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> 
> state_list <- unlist(strsplit(paste(df2$State, collapse = " "), ","))
> state_list
[1] "Alabama"        "North Caroline" " Virginia Ohio" " Kentucky"     
> 
> df1$Verified_State <- sapply(df1$State, function(x) {
+   grep(x, state_list, value = T)[1]
+ }, USE.NAMES = F)
> 
> df1
     State Verified_State
1  Alabama        Alabama
2 Maryland           <NA>
```

This assumes you need only the first match